# Haxe project not compiling

Tags: flash, haxe, openfl, lime-haxe

I was working on my game, when I noticed that a new version of OpenFL, Lime (if I remember correcly) and swf had been published. I updated the libraries, opened FlashDevelop again, and continued making my game. After a while, instead of successfully compiling on Flash, my IDE printed this error message on console;

```
Running process: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "C:\Users\Juha\Documents\Haxe Programs\Time4You\Time4You.hxproj" -ipc 1192a496-8b1d-4775-a939-9caf24483487 -version "3.1.3" -compiler "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe" -library "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Library" -target "flash"
Building Time4You
Running Pre-Build Command Line...
cmd: "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe/haxelib" run lime build "project.xml" flash -debug -Dfdb
Called from ? line 1
Called from CommandLineTools.hx line 1359
Called from CommandLineTools.hx line 25
Called from CommandLineTools.hx line 126
Called from CommandLineTools.hx line 579
Called from lime/project/PlatformTarget.hx line 70
Called from lime/tools/platforms/FlashPlatform.hx line 224
Called from lime/tools/helpers/FlashHelper.hx line 816
Called from lime/tools/helpers/FlashHelper.hx line 629
Called from format/swf/Writer.hx line 59
Called from format/swf/Writer.hx line 1255
Called from format/swf/Writer.hx line 1163
Called from format/swf/Writer.hx line 1121
Called from /usr/lib/haxe/std/haxe/io/Output.hx line 168
Uncaught exception - Overflow
Build halted with errors.
```

Any ideas what could cause this or how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try rolling back to the previous libs? What does your haxelib list say?

Also you could try the `-D legacy` compiler flag

Did you update each library individually? If you're using an engine of some sort ( eg haxe flixel ) there might be a version mismatch. If so, a haxelib upgrade might work.

I'd probably try these ( in reverse order ) before digging into exactly what has changed in the updated libs, if you haven't already

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I had updated the libraries with 'haxelib upgrade' command, and I'm not using any engines. Using -Dlegacy compiler flag unfortunately didn't help. I also tried setting my library versions to previous, but it didn't help either. My other project still works for some reason, so maybe I could create a new project and then copy the assets and classes there?

Comment: Hmmm, does it work in release mode? Or for other targets ( eg neko ) - thinking it might be related to fdb / Java heap size as in http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=6006

Comment: It works for HTML5 and Neko (I've not tried others), but it doesn't work for Flash either in Debug or Release mode.

Comment: Perhaps something in lime-tools isn't working for flash target - could try removing lime-tools from haxelib and reinstalling... Does the other working project you mentioned use lime-tools ( and the same version )?

Comment: Hmm... I finally managed to locate the problem, there was one line in the project.xml which caused the bug, but the problems just started so soon after I had updated the libraries, so I accidently thought the problem were somehow connected to them... Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @Kalakuh What was the line?  I'm getting the same build error.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference the problem is most likely to be caused by a damage / corrupt .hxproj file in most cases making another project or if you're using version control, rolling back that file will works best.